# Setting background image for PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

```
Swift iOS
xcode 7.1 Beta
```

I am trying to set background image on the `PFQueryTableViewController`. I tried dragging the table from the story board (Ref. outlet: tableView) but I am not able to make the code work referring to that outlet.

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "Background")
    tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

The app crashes stating:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:`.

I even tried setting the background color `tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()`

But again, the app crashes

Can someone explain what's going on in here? I searched online, but most of the posts are only related to fetching images inside the PFQueryTableViewController cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the same code inside the queryForTable() block that returns query. It should work. No need of reference outlet.

Code should be something like:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

  let image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")
  tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: image)

  // your PFQueryTableViewController query goes here.... 

  return query
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: wait what why set it in the `queryForTable`?? the error you're getting is because it can't load the nib file. How did this code fix your problem?

Comment: @lightice11 Do you have a better solution? Or anything wrong in this solution? Please elaborate. To your question, I have not added any nib file myself. I am using PFQueryTableViewController. Loading data inside that using Parse query.

Comment: @VickyArora could you post some more of your view controller code?